# Set Size of TextFieldRect.Width

Tags: c#, printing, rectangles, drawrectangle

Good day, our .Net developer has flown the coop and I am attempting to decipher the syntax utilized.  I have found the issue is that `TextSize.Width` = 104.7736 and `TextFieldRect.Width` = 100 so when it hits the `if()` statement in the `DrawLeftTextField` method the error is thrown.  Well my issue is, how do I change the `TextFieldRect.Width` to account for longer than 100?  Below is the syntax, and if further explanation is needed please let me know and I will do my best to explain further.

Edit --- what I am after here is to write text and the value of the text box on the top of the print page.

```
protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    // Run base code
    base.OnPrintPage(e);

    //Declare local variables needed
    int printHeight = 0;
    int printWidth = 0;
    int rightMargin = 0;

    PaperSize ps = default(PaperSize);
    for (int ix = 0; ix <= PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1; ix++)
    {
        if (PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[ix].Kind == PaperKind.A4)
        {
            ps = PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[ix];
            DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
            break;
        }
    }

    DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = PAGE_TOP_MARGIN;
    DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN;
    DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

    var CurrentPageSettings = base.DefaultPageSettings;
    printWidth = CurrentPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Top - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Bottom;
    printHeight = CurrentPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Left - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Right;
    m_leftMargin = CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Left; //X
    rightMargin = CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Top; //Y

    //Create a rectangle printing are for our document
    m_PrintArea = new RectangleF(m_leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight);

    // Get Normal Row Height
    int charactersFitted = 0;
    int linesFilled = 0;
    SizeF TextSize = new SizeF();
    StringFormat textFormat = new StringFormat();
    //Tell it to Alignment Text in its rectangle 
    textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
    textFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
    TextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("NORMALROW", SUB_HEADING_FONT, m_PrintArea.Size, textFormat, out charactersFitted, out linesFilled);
    m_NormalRowHeight = (int)TextSize.Height + 3;  

    DrawTextValuePair(e, "Employee Name: ", Control.maintenance.txtEmployee.Text, true, m_leftMargin);

    //More here
}

void DrawTextValuePair(PrintPageEventArgs e, string strText, string strValue, bool bDrawLine, int iLeftMargin)
{
    m_iCurrentLocationY += m_NormalRowHeight;
    Point LeftTextFieldLocation = new Point(iLeftMargin, m_iCurrentLocationY);
    DrawLeftTextField(e, strText, new Rectangle(LeftTextFieldLocation, m_TextValuePairSize), StringAlignment.Near);

    Point ValueFieldLocation = new Point(iLeftMargin + m_TextValuePairSize.Width, m_iCurrentLocationY);
    DrawValueField(e, strValue, new Rectangle(ValueFieldLocation, m_TextValuePairSize), StringAlignment.Far);

    if (bDrawLine)
    {
    int iRightEnd = iLeftMargin + (2 * m_TextValuePairSize.Width);
    int iYLocation = m_iCurrentLocationY + m_NormalRowHeight;
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(new Pen(Color.DarkBlue, 2), iLeftMargin, iYLocation, iRightEnd, iYLocation);
    }
}

void DrawLeftTextField(PrintPageEventArgs e, string strText, Rectangle TextFieldRect, StringAlignment TextAligment)
{
    int charactersFitted = 0;
    int linesFilled = 0;
    SizeF TextSize = new SizeF();
    StringFormat textFormat = new StringFormat();
    //Tell it to Alignment Text in its rectangle 
    textFormat.Alignment = TextAligment;
    textFormat.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    textFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
    TextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString(strText, NORMAL_TEXT_FONT, m_PrintArea.Size, textFormat, out charactersFitted, out linesFilled);
    if ((TextSize.Width > TextFieldRect.Width) || (TextSize.Height > TextFieldRect.Height))
    {
    Debug.Assert(false);
    return;
    }

    e.Graphics.DrawString(strText, NORMAL_TEXT_FONT, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), TextFieldRect, textFormat);

}
```

**EDIT**
I have hardcoded a length which is now not throwing an error and using the below syntax, however the text I want to display is just garbage, look at the screenshot

```
protected override void OnPrintPage(PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
// Run base code
base.OnPrintPage(e);

//Declare local variables needed
int printHeight = 0;
int printWidth = 0;
int rightMargin = 0;

PaperSize ps = default(PaperSize);
for (int ix = 0; ix <= PrinterSettings.PaperSizes.Count - 1; ix++)
{
    if (PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[ix].Kind == PaperKind.A4)
    {
        ps = PrinterSettings.PaperSizes[ix];
        DefaultPageSettings.PaperSize = ps;
        break;
    }
}

DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top = PAGE_TOP_MARGIN;
DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left = PAGE_LEFT_MARGIN;
DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = true;

var CurrentPageSettings = base.DefaultPageSettings;
printWidth = CurrentPageSettings.PaperSize.Height - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Top - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Bottom;
printHeight = CurrentPageSettings.PaperSize.Width - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Left - CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Right;
m_leftMargin = CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Left; //X
rightMargin = CurrentPageSettings.Margins.Top; //Y

//Create a rectangle printing are for our document
m_PrintArea = new RectangleF(m_leftMargin, rightMargin, printWidth, printHeight);

// Get Normal Row Height
int charactersFitted = 0;
int linesFilled = 0;
SizeF TextSize = new SizeF();
StringFormat textFormat = new StringFormat();
//Tell it to Alignment Text in its rectangle 
textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
textFormat.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoClip;
TextSize = e.Graphics.MeasureString("NORMALROW", SUB_HEADING_FONT, m_PrintArea.Size, textFormat, out charactersFitted, out linesFilled);
m_NormalRowHeight = (int)TextSize.Height + 3; //Row is bigger than text 

// draw logo
Image logoImage = global::SoilProfile.Properties.Resources.SoilProfileIcon.ToBitmap();
// get the size of the image
Rectangle LogoRect = new Rectangle(m_leftMargin, m_leftMargin, (int)(logoImage.Width * 0.75), (int)(logoImage.Height * 0.8));
e.Graphics.DrawImage(logoImage, LogoRect);
//e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.LightBlue, LogoRect);

//Draw First Heading
Rectangle MainHeaderRect = new Rectangle();
DrawMainHeading(e, LogoRect, ref MainHeaderRect);

m_iCurrentLocationY = MainHeaderRect.Bottom + (m_NormalRowHeight);

// Document Name
textFormat.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near;
Rectangle TextRect = new Rectangle(m_leftMargin, m_iCurrentLocationY, m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Width, m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Height);
e.Graphics.DrawString("Document Name: " + m_PrintData.DocumentName, SUB_HEADING_FONT, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), TextRect, textFormat);

int LeftSubHeadingWidth = 200;
m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize = new Size(LeftSubHeadingWidth, m_NormalRowHeight);

m_TextValuePairSize = new Size(m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Width / 30, m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Height);
DrawTextValuePair(e, "Name: ", Control.maintenance.txtEmployee.Text, true, m_leftMargin);
DrawTextValuePair(e, "Phone #: ", Control.maintenance.txtPhone.Text, true, m_leftMargin);
int iCurrentLocationX = m_leftMargin;
int iAlphaStart_Y = m_iCurrentLocationY;
iCurrentLocationX += m_SubHeaderTextFieldSize.Width + 30;
DrawTextValuePair(e, "Hire Date: ", DControl.maintenance.dtpDate.Text, true, iCurrentLocationX);
DrawTextValuePair(e, "Manager: ", Control.maintenance.txtManager.Text, true, iCurrentLocationX);
DrawTextValuePair(e, "District: ", Control.maintenance.txtDistrict.Text, true, iCurrentLocationX);

//More code here
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Okay, beyond syntax, I'd say the first question is figuring out the 'what' and 'why' of this code.

What it's doing:

- It's getting a string that it wants to print
- It's getting a rectangle it wants to print it at
- It's making sure the string that it wants to print will fit in that
  rectangle

... okay, so why is that error there?

```
if ((TextSize.Width > TextFieldRect.Width) || (TextSize.Height > TextFieldRect.Height))
{
    Debug.Assert(false);
    return;
}
```

... that's where they're checking to make sure the rectangle is big enough to fit the string.

So what are your options?

1. Change the code that, if something too long is passed in, instead of
   erroring, it simply shortens what it tries to print
2. Figure out what's calling the function with a rectangle to small to
   fit the text, and change it so that it has a larger rectangle or a
   smaller string
3. See if there's something that reduced the size of the rectangle
   recently (such as printer margin/size changes.

Hope that helps out.

Comment: I am passing data from a text box on a user form to the rectangle so size could vary.  Would I be better off, ignoring the rectangles all together and just stacking the data on top of one another at the top of the print page?

Comment: No.  I definitely wouldn't just blindly go down that route.  In your shoes, what I'd do is step through the code to figure out what 'strText' is generating the error.  Keep in mind, that error only occurs when someone tries to print something in too small of a rectangle (which if I'm reading it right, is simply the full width of the page.)  There may be a Way-Too-Long-Line that's being printed, and the error is legit: it can't be fit within the page.  Once you figure out what string/line-of-text is generating the error, then you can figure out how you want to deal with the problem.

Comment: I have been stepping through the code, that is how I isolated the line that was actually generating the error.  I am not sure how to expand the width of the rectangle, but will attempt to continue to step through and trace to isolate where that width is set.